I get a form id Error in Google App Script for FormApp.openById()
I am getting an error in my code.gs at line 2 of code -
Actual Code is:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const form = FormApp.openById('YOUR_FORM_ID');

I have replaced ('YOUR_FORM_ID') with my form id as located by the copied link to site where the form id is the string of letters and numbers immediately after the d/e/ in: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/XXXXX-XXXX/viewform?usp=sf_link (I have replaced the id for my form with the XXXXX-XXXX)
The error I am getting is:
Exception: The given item ID is invalid.
onFormSubmit
@ Code.gs:2
What is wrong?

Google Forms have different IDs for the edit view and the preview.  You should grab the 44-character ID from the URL that is shown when you are in the "Edit" view of the form.  The URL will look similar to the below:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1stABuosFNAcq8QEwObuZCvxIPeibTHzuS_i_CmfEE2Q/edit

Thank you very much. That is exactly where I was going wrong.
